# Securing communication between Kafka client and Zookeeper server

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, tls1.2, bitnami

I've configured both Kafka server and Zookeeper server to use SSL/TLS using the JKS. I've confirmed this using openssl. I'm using Bitnami Helm charts of Kafka and Zookeeper. Below is the log output from Kafka. I'm pretty sure that the Kafka client isn't sending requests to Zookeeper server securely because of the Zookeeper logs. How do I ensure Kafka client uses SSL/TLS. I think the kafka client needs to use a client.properties file when executing config commands with args. But I don't know how to pass this file in during configuration. The logs show that Kafka client is trying to add a user called zookeeperUser to Zookeeper. This communication is non secure.

Kafka Logs

```
 09:56:31.43
 09:56:31.43 Welcome to the Bitnami kafka container
 09:56:31.44 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-kafka
 09:56:31.44 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-kafka/issues
 09:56:31.44
 09:56:31.44 INFO  ==> ** Starting Kafka setup **
 09:56:31.56 DEBUG ==> Validating settings in KAFKA_* env vars...
 09:56:31.65 INFO  ==> Initializing Kafka...
 09:56:31.66 INFO  ==> No injected configuration files found, creating default config files
 09:56:32.96 INFO  ==> Configuring Kafka for inter-broker communications with SASL_SSL authentication.
 09:56:33.13 INFO  ==> Configuring Kafka for client communications with SASL_SSL authentication.
 09:56:33.43 INFO  ==> Custom JAAS authentication file detected. Skipping generation.
 09:56:33.43 WARN  ==> The following environment variables will be ignored: KAFKA_CLIENT_USERS, KAFKA_CLIENT_PASSWORDS, KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_USER, KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_PASSWORD, KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_USER and KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_PASSWORD
 09:56:33.44 INFO  ==> Creating users in Zookeeper
 09:56:33.44 DEBUG ==> Creating user zookeeperUser in zookeeper
Warning: --zookeeper is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Kafka.
Use --bootstrap-server instead to specify a broker to connect to.
Error while executing config command with args '--zookeeper zookeeper.default.svc.cluster.local:3181 --alter --add-config SCRAM-SHA-256=[iterations=8192,password=zookeeperPassword],SCRAM-SHA-512=[password=zookeeperPassword] --entity-type users --entity-name zookeeperUser'
kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.$anonfun$waitUntilConnected$3(ZooKeeperClient.scala:262)
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.waitUntilConnected(ZooKeeperClient.scala:258)
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.<init>(ZooKeeperClient.scala:119)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$.apply(KafkaZkClient.scala:1881)
        at kafka.admin.ConfigCommand$.processCommandWithZk(ConfigCommand.scala:116)
        at kafka.admin.ConfigCommand$.main(ConfigCommand.scala:94)
        at kafka.admin.ConfigCommand.main(ConfigCommand.scala)
```

client.properties

```
cat > client.properties <<EOF
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256
ssl.truststore.location=/tmp/kafka.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=******
EOF
```

Zookeeper Logs

```
2021-02-11 09:56:43,055 [myid:1] - ERROR [nioEventLoopGroup-7-1:NettyServerCnxnFactory$CertificateVerifier@434] - Unsuccessful handshake with session 0x0
2021-02-11 09:56:43,055 [myid:1] - WARN  [nioEventLoopGroup-7-1:NettyServerCnxnFactory$CnxnChannelHandler@273] - Exception caught
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record: 0000002d000000000000000000000000000075300000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:471)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record: 0000002d000000000000000000000000000075300000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1246)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1314)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:501)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:440)
        ... 17 more
```

Comment: I'd recommend you to create an issue in https://github.com/bitnami/charts as it is easier to provide support there. Also, check this in case it helps: https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/kafka#enable-security-for-kafka-and-zookeeper